# Installing MySQL Dev Client on Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.4

When I try running

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

I get the following

> Reading package lists...
>
> Done Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information...
>
> Done libmysqlclient-dev is already the newest
>   version.
>
> Some packages could not be installed.
>
> This may mean that you
>   have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the
>   unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been
>   created or been moved out of Incoming.
>
> The following information may
>   help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  python-pip : Depends:
>   python-setuptools (>= 0.6c1) but it is not going to be installed
>                 Depends: python-requests but it is not going to be installed
>                 Recommends: python-dev-all (>= 2.6) but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
>   packages

Answer (score 0):

The Error says that you libmysqlclient-dev is already installed and on the newest version.

Please check that.

But it also says you need the following packages:

```
python-setuptools
python-requests
python-dev-all
```

Consider downloading/updating these via `pip install` and then try again :)

Comment: python-pip : Depends: python-requests but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-dev-all (>= 2.6) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages...